# Testing JSON mapping for a Spring Boot RestTemplate client

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, resttemplate

I have a REST API outside of my control (supplied by a different, distant team) which I need to consume from a Spring Boot application.

Currently I would like to write a test for that the **request** (not response)  resulting from my RestTemplate invocation corresponds exactly to what is expected at the remote end.  I have a sample JSON snippet that I would like to replicate from my code - given the same parameters as in the sample I should get an equivalent JSON snippet in the request body which I would then like to analyze to be certain.

My idea so far is to get RestTemplate to use a server under my control which then captures the JSON request.  Apparently `MockRestServiceServer` is a good choice for this.

Is this the right approach?  How do I configure MockRestServiceServer to allow me to do this?

Comment: So you want to test a third party service? What will happen if it is down for like 3 weeks? You won't have your application running?

Comment: Do you know the API of the dependent service well?

Comment: Also, is this an integration test and are there many?

Comment: You can check if MockMvc will be suitable for you. You can create requests using methods in MockHttpServletRequestBuilder class.

Comment: @VeselinDavidov No, I want to ensure that the JSON I generate and send is as expected.  I do not need to actually reach the remote service in the test.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're only interested in verifying the JSON mapping, you can always use Jackson's `ObjectMapper` directly and verify if the object structures match by using a library like [JSONassert](http://jsonassert.skyscreamer.org/) to verify if the serialized string matches your expected result. For example:

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
private Resource expectedResult = new ClassPathResource("expected.json");

@Test
public void jsonMatches() {
    Foo requestBody = new Foo();
    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestBody);
    String expectedJson = Files
        .lines(expectedResult.getFile())
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
    JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedJson, json, JSONCompareMode.LENIENT);
}
```

This test purely uses `ObjectMapper` to verify the JSON mapping and nothing else, so you could even do this without actually having to bootstrap Spring boot within your test (which could be faster). The downside of this is that if you're using a different framework than Jackson, or if `RestTemplate` changes its implementation, that this test could become obsolete.

---

Alternatively, if you're interesting in verifying that the complete request matches (both URL, request method, request body and so on), you can use `MockRestServiceServer` as you mentioned. This can be done by adding the `@SpringBootTest` annotation to your test, autowiring `RestTemplate` and the service that invokes `RestTemplate` for example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FooServiceTests {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService; // Your service

    private MockRestServiceServer server;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        server = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build();
    }
}
```

You can then set up your tests by using:

```
@Test
public void postUsesRestTemplate() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    Path resource = Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("expected-foo.json").toURI());
    String expectedJson = Files.lines(resource).collect(Collectors.joining());
    server.expect(once(), requestTo("http://example.org/api/foo"))
        .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
        .andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.content().json(expectedJson))
        .andRespond(withSuccess());
    // Invoke your service here
    fooService.post();
    server.verify();
}
```

Comment: Yes.  I would like to verify the JSON mapping _actually_ used though by the RestTemplate.  To my understanding this doesn't do that?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen This test verifies if Jackson creates the proper JSON string for your object. Considering that `RestTemplate` uses a list of messageconverters, and by default will use Jackson to create the JSON string, this test should yield the same result.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I also included an example with `MockRestServiceServer`, which is what you were looking for.

Comment: I ended up using both, first to get the AutoValue beans to map correctly and then to actually do the test.  Very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation, you could match requests using json paths on Mock. For example;

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate()
 MockRestServiceServer server = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build();

server.expect(ExpectedCount.once(), requestTo(path))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].someField").value("some value"))
```

Note: I haven't tested this.

But I have achieved what you are looking for using Wire Mock many times. That's again a much better option than `MockRestServiceServer`. Why do I say so?

- wide adoption and support
- more elegant and extensive request & response matching
- highly configurable
- record and playback
- configurable security/auth
- you could even dockerise this

Have a look at http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/

Comment: Interesting. Does WireMock use a network port or is it fully internal?

Comment: It indeed allows you to configure ports - http://wiremock.org/docs/configuration/

Comment: I don't want to use a port if I possibly can help it.

Comment: Well, the default http port is 8080

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach using a stub server (you could use [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/docs/verifying/) for this) is fine if you want to check once, manually.

Alternatively you could add a [request logger](https://objectpartners.com/2018/03/01/log-your-resttemplate-request-and-response-without-destroying-the-body/) to your RestTemplate which logs each request. That would make it easier to check if the sent request is correct any time if problems arise.

Comment: I want this to eventually be a regression test in my solution to help future maintainers.

Comment: If you make a test which checks the request against a static value you will not notice if the remote service undergoes a change. The best regression test here would be an integration test which calls the actual service (e.g. on an acceptance environment of theirs, if possible) and verifies the result. If the request is incorrect then presumably the response will not be either - and isn't that what matters in the end?

Comment: Yes.  The regression test I need is whether the JSON mapping in my solution always stays 100% accurate to the provided documentation, even when doing heavy refactoring (or trying to).   The remote end will (probably) not change without due notification, so this is not what I want to ensure.